# SQL Server job step retry attempts

Tags: sql-server-2008

SQL server job steps have a setting for 'retry attempts'; if a job fails for some reason, depending on the setting, SQL server tries to restart the SQL job.

We have this setting (5 attempts) for our replication agents which run continuously.

I need to know, how many counts I have exhausted so far. For e.g. If the if a agent has already failed 4 times, I'd rather stop and start the agent which will reset the counter, than wait for it to fail during off hours.

Is there a way to get how many tries have been already done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View the job history. Open the current execution. It should contain a column named `Retries Attempted`. You might have to scroll to the right a bit, it's one of the last columns.

[image]